# Почему webpack-dev-server не перезапускает страницу?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

**webpack-dev-server** не перезагружает страницу после ошибке в **js** файле.
С этой проблемой так же встречаются и другие люди, но ответов я так и не нашел.

**Примеры:**

[Webpack dev server stops refresh the page if there's an error in app.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551999/webpack-5-dev-server-does-not-reload-on-file-changes)

[Webpack-dev-server is not detecting file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392972/webpack-dev-server-is-not-detecting-file-changes)

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

// Временная переменная, которая определяет режим сборки.
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;

// Источник: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/pages/index.js'),
  // entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    // publicPath: '/js/',
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  // target: NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'web' : 'browserslist',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    // publicPath: './js/',
    // contentBase: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
    // hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My template",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --node-env development",
    "prod": "webpack --node-env production"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "js",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "Devinora <kh.devinora@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": " ",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.24.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  }
}
```

**файловая структура**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в максимальном значение числа дескрипторов, за которыми может наблюдать пользователь. Возникала аналогичная ситуация. Подлечила следующая команда:

```
sudo sh -c "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
```